# Ubuntu command to copy file only if origin is not empty

Tags: shell, curl, cron

I have a cronjob getting a list of prices from a website in JSON format and copying it into the right folder and it looks like this:

`curl 'https://somesite.web/api/list.json' > ~/list.json.tmp && cp ~/list.json.tmp /srv/www/list.json > /dev/null`

The problem is that a couple of times the website was down while the cron was trying to get the list and got an empty JSON file. To prevent this in the future, is there a way to make the cron only copy the file if it's not empty (no cp option to do this)? or should I create a script to do that and call the script after getting the list?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
curl ... && [ -s ~/list/json.tmp ] && cp ~/list/json.tmp /srv/www/list.json
```

The `-s` test is true if the named file exists and is not empty.

(Incidentally, the `> /dev/null` redirection is not necessary. The `cp` command might print error messages to stderr, but it shouldn't print anything to stdout, which is what you're redirecting.)

Comment: That worked perfectly. Thanks for the quick response.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe `curl --fail` will accomplish what you want? From the man page:

> -f, --fail
>       (HTTP) Fail silently (no output at all) on server errors. This is mostly done to better enable scripts etc to better deal with failed attempts. In normal cases when an HTTP server fails to deliver a  document, it returns an HTML document stating so (which often also describes why and more). This flag will prevent curl from outputting that and return error 22.

This would cause curl to exit with a failure code, and thus the `&&` in your statement would not execute the copy.